# How to dual-boot on a machine with PGP WDE?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, grub2, dual-boot, pgp

PGP Whole disk encryption ("WDE") is an encryption software that encrypts all your data, and includes a bootguard. Because of this, I have been unable to successfully dual-boot, as there is no place to install GRUB. (I did attempt an install, the result of which was a complete loss of my Windows partition, and a completely shot weekend.)

I attempted the Ubuntu dual-boot (wubi version, does not install bootloader), but since the sequence is PGP decrytption-bootloader-OS, the data necessary for the install were inaccessible. The computer is a work computer, and I have not been granted permission to decrypt it.

I'm booting off an external drive for now, but are there any good means of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install GRUB (instead of the whole OS) on a USB stick or CD and use that for booting. Having such a boot medium is generally nice (at least on non-UEFI systems, if a system gets so screwed up that it doesn't boot any more).

Comment: My understanding is that PGP WDE prevents the decryption of native files, even if the OS is externally booloaded (pardon my grammar). 

However, it is certainly worth a try. I may attempt this today. If it works, I will mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Qu0rk My understanding of your question is that you have installed Ubuntu on the disk and just need a boot loader for it. WDE is no magic tool. They cannot erase the partition table because then the BIOS / UEFI would not boot any more. I do not see how such a software could prevent you from installing another OS (if the first one does not cover the whole drive).

Comment: It worked! Much appreciated- This will greatly simplify my setup.

Comment: @Qu0rk - I know this was some time ago, but *what* worked? I am faced with the same requirement, except that I want to install the likes of Grub to chain load two different versions of Windows. I am unclear from your response whether booting off a USB stick (and having access to the files on the internal HDD) was what you got to work, or whether you got GRUB to load after PGP WDE to the chain load your two OS'?